# JSF 2 f:param inside of ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameters, hyperlink, parameter-passing

as the question above mentiones, i need to create "dynamic" params for a

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:link>
        <h:outputText value="link with params" />
        <ui:repeat var="parameter" value="#{bean.getCurrentParameter}"> //customClass

            test: #{parameter.name} #{parameter.value} //output is fine

            <f:param name="#{parameter.name}" value="#{parameter.value}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:link>
</ui:composition>
```

unfortunately the "test" returns all values correctly, but when I hover the link, there is not a single parameter set ("page.xhtml" instead of "page.xhtml?param1=ddd&param2=sss...")

To unterstand why I need this, I want to get all parameters of the current page and add/remove one (the link clicked on is the one I want to remove/add).

to I need to generate for each link its own parameters (when param1=1,2 by default, one link has e.g. "param1=1,2,3" (appends 3) and the other one has "param1=1,2,4" (appends 4))

Comment: Your test looks wrong. Try to create the `<h:link>` **inside** `<ui:repeat>` instead. Also, looks like your `<h:outputText/>` has a typo since it is not properly closed.

Comment: Hi, I cannot put the h:link inside, because I don't want many links with one parameter, I want ONE link with many parameters. i hope the question is more clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic [taghandlers vs component tags](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) issue. `<ui:repeat/>` is a component tag that runs after the view tree has been built while `<f:param/>` is a tag handler that is placed in the view tree during view build. What this means is that `<f:param/>` is parsed and processed before `<ui:repeat/>` ever makes it into the page. As a result `var="parameter"` is not available for use when `<f:param/>` needs it.

To fix, use the `<c:forEach/>` tag instead:

```
<h:link>
   <h:outputText value="link with params" />
   <c:forEach var="parameter" items="#{bean.getCurrentParameter}">
       test: #{parameter.name} #{parameter.value}
        <f:param name="#{parameter.name}" value="#{parameter.value}" />
   </c:forEach>
</h:link>
```